# Why many Metadata properties are not supported in BitmapMetadata("png")?

Tags: c#, png, metadata

I am trying to create  a PNG BitmapMetadata object to set few arguments. But many of them seem not supported. I am using .Net 4.0 version.

```
 BitmapMetadata meta = new BitmapMetadata("png");
 meta.Comment = "PNG image comment" // <- throws NotSupported exception
```

Almost all Metadata properties here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata(v=vs.110).aspx#NotExistJustToMakeTheAElementVisible are not supported when I create a png instance of BitmapMetadata.

'(meta).ApplicationName' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Comment: See the PNG specification. It simply doesn't support many of these metadata properties (which are based on EXIF, itself not supported by PNG files).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Indeed it doesn't, but it does support the comment property: http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11textinfo. That's what I find so peculiar.

Comment: @PeterDuniho when I try to add textual PNG metadata using SetQuery() it still doesnt work.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it still doesn't work"? Are you saying it still throws the same exception? Or that it fails in some other way? Please update your question with whatever new information you have.

Comment: Also, I see that your question is garnering some downvotes. This may be because the question is sparse on detail, including the lack of [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like the following for PNGs:

```
BitmapMetadata meta = new BitmapMetadata("png");
meta.SetQuery("/tEXt/{str=Comment}", "PNG image comment");
```

Comment: Noting, however, that this is "by convention" only and not a part of the official PNG specification. Only some programs will recognize data inserted as a `tEXt` chunk like that as an image comment.

Comment: hmmm...that was just what I came up with off the top of my head. Now I'm curious so I'll toy around with it in VS for a little bit.

Comment: I tried to use SetQuery(). But when I assign the metadata to pngencoder for creating png image, it throws exception saying 'The designated BitmapEncoder does not support global metadata.'